# Is it possibly to patch code onto __init__ from within a method decorator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators, syntactic-sugar

I want to create a property decorator that computes the property value once upon object initialization, rather than every time the property is accessed. For example:

```
class Foo:

  def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value

  @cached_property  # How to implement this decorator?
  def foo(self):
    return self.value * some_heavy_computation()
```

I'd like this be equivalent to:

```
class Foo:

  def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value
    self._foo = self.value * some_heavy_computation()

  @property
  def foo(self):
    return self._foo
```

Is it possible to somehow add code to `__init__()` from within the method decorator?

Comment: At the time a method decorator is evaluated, the class itself does not exist yet, so there's no way you could look up its ``__init__`` method to modify it, even if it had been defined already (which isn't something you could count on).  However, you could write a decorator that calls the wrapped function only the first time, saves the value in an instance variable, and afterwards just returns the cached value.

Comment: Why do you think you need to add code to `__init__`? You should read up on the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).

Comment: @jasonharper Couldn't I get `__init__` of the same `cls` and replace it with a patched `__init__`? Let's say I'm assuming `__init__` is always defined before the other methods.

Comment: What class?  There is no class until the entire body of its definition (including all decorated methods) has completed execution.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks for the clarification. I'd prefer lazy evaluation upon first access of the properties, but the method bodies require resources that are not available at that time anymore. I'd be happy to hear your thoughts on the solution below.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for pointing out descriptors. I don't see how they can be applied here though, as they don't allow to run code right after `__init__`. That's needed, unfortunately, since the method bodies require resources not available at the time the properties will get accessed.

Comment: Your example does not explain why that would even be necessary; could you provide some more appropriate context? This seems like a http://xyproblem.info

Answer (score 0):

We need to sub class `property` so that we can later find all the cached properties of the object and initialize them after `__init__`:

```
class CachedProperty(property):

  pass
```

The actual decorator evaluates the method body when called for the first time, and remembers the result for later accesses:

```
import functools

def cached_property(method):
  attribute = '_cached_' + method.__name__

  @CachedProperty
  @functools.wraps(method)
  def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not hasattr(self, attribute):
      setattr(self, attribute, method(self))
    return getattr(self, attribute)

  return wrapper
```

Now we can use a base class to access the cached properties after `__init__` so that the values will be available from the cache:

```
class InitCachedProperties:

  def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
    super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
    orig_init = cls.__init__
    def init(self, *args, **kwargs):
      orig_init(self, *args, **kwargs)
      for prop in cls.__dict__.values():
        if isinstance(prop, CachedProperty):
          prop.__get__(self)
    cls.__init__ = init
```

To make the example from the question work, we need to let our class inherit from this property initializing base class:

```
class Foo(InitCachedProperties):

    def __init__(self, value):
      self.value = value

    @cached_property
    def foo(self):
      return self.value + 21
```